# matlab urlread not retrieving all content

Tags: html, matlab, urlread

I was trying to retrieve html as a string by using urlread function. But, urlread does not retrieve the whole html bu just a small part. I compared the html of urls through browser to html through matlab. Matlab retireves about 15% of total.

What I need to do to automatically read the whole html? I was really diasspointed I started to learn other languages so as finsh my project... Please help me!

Comment: could you please give an example of an URL and its incomplete output?

Comment: url:http:www.4xinvestmentgroup.com

check the source code from chrome versus to html coming from urlread